# How do I addFilter to core/paragraph to add an attribute and see the change in the editor?

Tags: block-editor

I have been trying to extend core block in wp gutenberg. I am able to add filters and controls but not able to see the changes I apply to the controls in the editor, the changes are applied on save mode by the filter, but not in the edit mode.